# UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString broken?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

the following code should open the notification settings of my app. However it only opens the settings app. Anyone else experience this?

```
if let settings = URL(string: UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settings)
}
```

`UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` works as expected and opens the settings of my app.

Comment: When you look at your app’s entry in the Apple Settings app do you see a row for notification settings? That is, is there a notification settings screen to navigate to? If not, have you requested permission to send notifications yet? I think the notification settings page only comes into existence when you request authorisation to send notifications.

Comment: Hello, yes, i have requested notifications and they are displayed in the settings app.

Comment: File a bug with Apple.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the iOS Simulator. Have you tried running your code on a real device? I had the same issue with the simulator but on the physical device it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: This does not seem to be a Simulator issue, I can reproduce it on a real device with iOS 17.0.3.